# Align Labels in Grid WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

I'm having an alignment issue, I'm trying to position the labels from start to end but they're starting in the middle. Can someone shed some light on what I need to do to change it and get it aligned how I want.

[image]

```
        <Grid Height="23.3" Margin="169,0,8,8.199" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Fill="#FFDDDDDD" Stroke="#FFD7D7D7" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>


            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lblAbout" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.about]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FF585858" FontSize="10" Cursor="Hand" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" MouseLeftButtonUp="lblAbout_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.settings]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FF585858" FontSize="10" Cursor="Hand" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.feedback]}" Foreground="#FF585858" FontSize="10" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.help]}" Foreground="#FF585858" FontSize="10" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.checkingUpdates]}" Foreground="#FF585858" FontSize="10" Cursor="Hand" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Well, you realize you're starting in column 1, rather than column 0, so from the start you're one column over?  I'm not sure how you want them to align, maybe you can photoshop the image to demonstrate what you want, are you wanting basically to just have them stringing from left to right without a lot of space in between (kind of like a menu strip)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've changed my code to start from col 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, since all of your columns are using star sizing, they will all be even sized and stretched across the width.

I believe you want:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```

This will cause them to stack left to right, and "fill" at the end.

Comment: Just what I needed! The most smallest change makes the biggest difference. Thanks a lot!